# Why this ListView Custom Adapter with CheckBoxes behaving in an odd way?

Tags: android

My ListView Custom Adapter with Check Boxes behaving in an odd way.when I check any check box and scroll it up and down then my application check checkboxes randomly.I'm very confused.

Here is getView function

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 final ViewHolder holder;
  if (convertView == null) {
        convertView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent,
                false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    }
  holder.checkBox.setText(Name[position]);
    return convertView;
}
```

ViewHoder.java class

```
 public class ViewHolder {
 CheckBox checkBox;
 }
```

String in MainActivity.java class

```
 String[] names=new String[]{
            "Name1" , "Name2" , "Name3" ,"Name4" , "Name5" , "Name6","Name7"         , "Name8" , "Name9","Name10" , "Name11" , "Name12"};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure if this is the cause but it could be one of the following:

- Make your view holder class static so that there's only one instance of it.
- Why are you inflating the layout every time getView is called (it gets called a LOT); do it in the constructor and assign a member variable for later access.
- I don't think it's required, but make sure you initialize your check box to checked = false.

Otherwise, your code looks fine to me, I'm not on my Dev machine so I can't test my suggestions. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'checked' state of the checkbox in getView (e.g. right after you call setText.

Right now, one of the views gets it's checkbox checked when you click on it, and then that view is re-used in other positions, but retains it checked state.